# ¿Es posible actualizar un campo del registro anterior de la misma tabla mediante un TRIGGER - AFTER INSERT?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER cuentas_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `cuentas` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

declare variable integer;
select max(CuentaCodigo) into variable from cuenta;

update cuentas
set Cuentaestado = 0
where Cuentacodigo = variable;

END
```

Esta es la tabla donde quiero implementar el trigger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible crear un procedimiento actualizado para realizar está acción, pero en sí mi consulta es determinar si puedo hacerlo mediante un trigger para no involucrar más procesos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues parece que no hay forma de modificar la misma tabla con la que salta el disparador:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673

Por lo visto es para prevenir situaciones de recursividad infinita.

Probando con algo así, salta el error del artículo del enlace:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cuentas_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON cuentas
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE cuentas
      set CuentaEstado=0
      WHERE CuentaCodigo=NEW.CuentaCodigo-1;      
  END;
```

Vas a tener que hacerlo en dos pasos: primero el `INSERT` y después el `UPDATE` sin disparador.

Comment: Gracias David por tu apoyo.